What is the best way to get rid of those lines?
The lines marked by red circle



Hello what does it give if you right click in Object mode > Shade Flat?

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Please verbally describe what your issue is, be specific and and use relevant keywords. Avoid referencing images or links as alternative to words, try to stay away from vague references like "this happens", "issue with", "like so", which make the post impossible to find for someone using search. Instead describe what "it" is, be descriptive, succinct and detailed. It may not be immediately obvious to users trying to help what you mean. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

It looks as if your geometry isn't flat in those areas. You could fix this in Edit Mode:

Set your Transform Orientation to Normal:

Select all the faces that are supposed to be coplanar.
Press SZ0⏎ Enter to scale them to zero on their Normal Z axis, which should flatten them:



If the geometry of the object needs to remain the same, you might try smoothing the mesh.
You need to use 'smooth by angle' on object mode.
